# Find records in mongo db with regular expression search on certain field gives incorrect answer

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have query,

```
db.getCollection(collection).find({$and: [
  {street: {$regex: new RegExp('7/838(B) Seaport - Airport Road', 'i')}}
]})
```

the db contain the exact data, but returns nothing. How to write a correct query for get the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You don't need $and for that.

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({"street" : new RegExp("7/838(B) Seaport - Airport Road","i")})
```

Comment: Can you please explain why $regex is not needed ?Thank you in advance.

Comment: `{"street" : {$regex: /7/838(B) Seaport - Airport Road/i}}` check this.